# Calculate required equipment on shifts in timespans

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I would like to visualize the number of required machines in a jobshop at a certain time in graph with on the x-axis a continuous time axis and on the y-axis the number of shifts.

In the dataframe below, you find an example of my data. Here, you see `Shift_ID`s (which are unique) and the start and end time of that shift. Over a period of a day, I would like to see how many machines are needed at a certain interval. This can be 5 minutes, quarter of an hour, half an hour and hours.

```
df:
   Shift_ID     Shift_Time_Start       Shift_Time_End
0         1   2016-03-22 9:00:00   2016-03-22 9:35:00
1         2   2016-03-22 9:20:00  2016-03-22 10:20:00
2         3   2016-03-22 9:40:00  2016-03-22 10:14:00
3         4  2016-03-22 10:00:00  2016-03-22 10:31:00
```

In this example in the quarter 9:30-9:45 I would need 3 machines to be able to do every shift at that specific time. The desired output would look something like this:

```
df2:

                                    Interval  Count
0    2016-03-22 9:00:00 - 2016-03-22 9:15:00      1
1    2016-03-22 9:15:00 - 2016-03-22 9:30:00      2
2    2016-03-22 9:30:00 - 2016-03-22 9:45:00      3
3   2016-03-22 9:45:00 - 2016-03-22 10:00:00      2
4  2016-03-22 10:00:00 - 2016-03-22 10:15:00      2
5  2016-03-22 10:15:00 - 2016-03-22 10:30:00      2
6  2016-03-22 10:30:00 - 2016-03-22 10:45:00      1
```

With this data frame i could round it to the the lowest boundary of the interval and then plot it in a graph.

I get stuck on how to "see" whether a shift lies within multiple intervals. Do you have any ideas how to tackle this?

NB: All date-time values are of course datetime type

**EDIT after Solution of MaxU and knightofni**

I used the code of MaxU to plot both your codes. They both seem to do it well on 15min but please take a look at you results with 5 minutes:

MaxU:

[image]

knightofni:

[image]

**EDIT 2  4 april 2015**

Comment: Thanks for editing Xiong Chiamiov!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not too easy. I can't really think of a way to do it completely vectorized way, but here are 2 approaches who will work.

1- Reorganize your data so that you have only one datetime column. The objective is to have, for each *shift_ID*, one row per *minimum interval*. Then you will be able to to a timegrouper groupby.

Working Example :

### Recreating your DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import arrow

data = {
    'Shift_ID' : [1,2,3,4],
    'Shift_Time_Start' : [arrow.get('2016-03-22 09:00:00').datetime, 
                   arrow.get('2016-03-22 09:20:00').datetime,
                   arrow.get('2016-03-22 09:40:00').datetime,
                   arrow.get('2016-03-22 10:00:00').datetime
                   ],

    'Shift_Time_End' : [arrow.get('2016-03-22 09:35:00').datetime, 
                   arrow.get('2016-03-22 10:20:00').datetime,
                   arrow.get('2016-03-22 10:14:00').datetime,
                   arrow.get('2016-03-22 10:31:00').datetime
                   ],   
        }


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
min_int = '5T'
df

Shift_ID    Shift_Time_End  Shift_Time_Start
0   1   2016-03-22 09:35:00+00:00   2016-03-22 09:00:00+00:00
1   2   2016-03-22 10:20:00+00:00   2016-03-22 09:20:00+00:00
2   3   2016-03-22 10:14:00+00:00   2016-03-22 09:40:00+00:00
3   4   2016-03-22 10:31:00+00:00   2016-03-22 10:00:00+00:00
```

### Creating New Df

```
new_data = {'time' : [], 'Shift_ID': []} # dict to hold the data

for row in df.iterrows():
    # creates a list of all dates of this shift, from start to end
    dates = pd.date_range(row[1].Shift_Time_Start, row[1].Shift_Time_End, freq=min_int)
    for date in dates:
        new_data['time'].append(date)
        new_data['Shift_ID'].append(row[1].Shift_ID)

# creating the new df    
newdf = pd.DataFrame(new_data).set_index('time')
newdf.head()


Shift_ID
time    
2016-03-22 09:00:00+00:00   1
2016-03-22 09:05:00+00:00   1
2016-03-22 09:10:00+00:00   1
2016-03-22 09:15:00+00:00   1
2016-03-22 09:20:00+00:00   1
```

### Groupby Timegrouper

```
# We groupby the time column, resampling every min_int 
# (in our case 5 minutes, represented by '5T'), 
# then we check how many uniquer shift_id.
newdf.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq=min_int)).agg({'Shift_ID': lambda x : len(set(x))})

    Shift_ID
time    
2016-03-22 09:00:00+00:00   1
2016-03-22 09:05:00+00:00   1
2016-03-22 09:10:00+00:00   1
2016-03-22 09:15:00+00:00   1
2016-03-22 09:20:00+00:00   2
2016-03-22 09:25:00+00:00   2
2016-03-22 09:30:00+00:00   2
2016-03-22 09:35:00+00:00   2
2016-03-22 09:40:00+00:00   2
```

This reads as *at 9:15, there was one shift going on, while at 9:20, there were 2*

This is not exactly your desired output, but i'd argue that this is much easier to plot.  If you want to match your desired output it should be quite easy (just use `.shift` to create copy of the date column moved by one).

** Edit

[Link to notebook with code](https://gist.github.com/knightofni/76acb1c7fb2983077b35df10ee59dd67)

Comment: Hi Knightofni, many thanks for you solution, I will look at it tonight thoroughly. As for what i can see now, the output does not match the desired output when i change the interval to 30 minutes. It then says that it has only 1 at 9:30. Since the real data is on seconds, i think it will cause some trouble with plotting. I will show it tonight with more detail

Comment: Hi, Uis, i get 3 at 9:30 when set to 30 mins. You can have a look at my notebook here https://gist.github.com/knightofni/76acb1c7fb2983077b35df10ee59dd67

Comment: Hi knightofni, Yesterday i was a little bit too tired to look at it, my apologies. It seems your code is almost right. It takes all into account but does something wrong when i change the interval to 5 min. Could you also give a  explanation about the +00:00 behind all datetimes. I am not familiar with the arrow package. Thanks for you help!!!!

Comment: Dear Knightofni, took a while but I implemented your code now. It gives the correct plots and indeed, you are right on the output. this is much better. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

Code:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load sample data into DF (data frame)
data="""\
idx;Shift_ID;Shift_Time_Start;Shift_Time_End
0;1;2016-03-22 09:00:00;2016-03-22 09:35:00
1;2;2016-03-22 09:20:00;2016-03-22 10:20:00
2;3;2016-03-22 09:40:00;2016-03-22 10:14:00
3;4;2016-03-22 10:00:00;2016-03-22 10:31:00
4;5;2016-03-22 08:11:00;2016-03-22 09:35:00
4;6;2016-03-23 14:11:00;2016-03-23 14:23:00
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=';', index_col=0,
                 parse_dates=['Shift_Time_Start','Shift_Time_End'])


# time interval
freq = '10min'

# prepare resulting DF with desired intervals
a  = pd.DataFrame({
  'begin': pd.date_range(df.Shift_Time_Start.min(),
                         df.Shift_Time_End.max(), freq=freq)
})
# resample 
a = a.set_index('begin').resample(rule='5min').first().reset_index()

a['end'] = a.begin + pd.Timedelta(freq)

# count number of unique Shift_ID's in `DF` for each interval in `a`
def f(x):
    return  df[( (x.begin >= df.Shift_Time_Start) \
                 & \
                 (x.begin <= df.Shift_Time_End)
               ) \
               | \
               ( (x.end >= df.Shift_Time_Start) \
                 & \
                 (x.end <= df.Shift_Time_End)
               ) \
              ].Shift_ID.nunique()


a['count'] = a.apply(f, axis=1)
# remove rows without any shifts
a = a[a['count'] > 0].reset_index(drop=True)


a['interval'] = a.begin.dt.strftime('%d.%m %H:%M').astype(str) + \
                ' - ' + \
                a.end.dt.strftime('%d.%m %H:%M').astype(str)

a = a.set_index('interval')[['count']]
print(a)

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

a.plot(kind='bar', alpha=0.75)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Source data set:

```
In [135]: df
Out[135]:
     Shift_ID    Shift_Time_Start      Shift_Time_End
idx
0           1 2016-03-22 09:00:00 2016-03-22 09:35:00
1           2 2016-03-22 09:20:00 2016-03-22 10:20:00
2           3 2016-03-22 09:40:00 2016-03-22 10:14:00
3           4 2016-03-22 10:00:00 2016-03-22 10:31:00
4           5 2016-03-22 08:11:00 2016-03-22 09:35:00
4           6 2016-03-23 14:11:00 2016-03-23 14:23:00

In [136]: a
Out[136]:
                           count
interval
22.03 08:10 - 22.03 08:20      1
22.03 08:15 - 22.03 08:25      1
22.03 08:20 - 22.03 08:30      1
22.03 08:25 - 22.03 08:35      1
22.03 08:30 - 22.03 08:40      1
22.03 08:35 - 22.03 08:45      1
22.03 08:40 - 22.03 08:50      1
22.03 08:45 - 22.03 08:55      1
22.03 08:50 - 22.03 09:00      2
22.03 08:55 - 22.03 09:05      2
22.03 09:00 - 22.03 09:10      2
22.03 09:05 - 22.03 09:15      2
22.03 09:10 - 22.03 09:20      3
22.03 09:15 - 22.03 09:25      3
22.03 09:20 - 22.03 09:30      3
22.03 09:25 - 22.03 09:35      3
22.03 09:30 - 22.03 09:40      4
22.03 09:35 - 22.03 09:45      4
22.03 09:40 - 22.03 09:50      2
22.03 09:45 - 22.03 09:55      2
22.03 09:50 - 22.03 10:00      3
22.03 09:55 - 22.03 10:05      3
22.03 10:00 - 22.03 10:10      3
22.03 10:05 - 22.03 10:15      3
22.03 10:10 - 22.03 10:20      3
22.03 10:15 - 22.03 10:25      2
22.03 10:20 - 22.03 10:30      2
22.03 10:25 - 22.03 10:35      1
22.03 10:30 - 22.03 10:40      1
23.03 14:05 - 23.03 14:15      1
23.03 14:10 - 23.03 14:20      1
23.03 14:15 - 23.03 14:25      1
23.03 14:20 - 23.03 14:30      1
```

Comment: Hi MaxU, although i really like your approach by taking the every possible interval between a begin and end, it does not return the right number (3) between 9:30 and 9:45, it returns 2. Furthermore, when i adjust the interval to 5 minutes, it does take into account that a shift can be longer than an interval. See the figure above. Thanks for you help!!! Much appreciated!!!!

Comment: @Uis234, IMO, there are only 2 Shift_ID's for the interval 9:30 to 9:45 - ID's: 1 and 2

Comment: Sorry you are totally right. My mistake. However, the skip of intervals is still not correct right?

Comment: Hi MaxU, I have put it to the test in my real data and think it did the trick! But there are a few small flaws. 1. I would like to see the time brackets predetermined starting from a whole hour (See knightofni's answer). If i run your code on my data this is not the case. For example: The Jobshop opens at 8, the first shift_ID is at 8:11, then the axis & timespans begin at 8:11 - 8:16. I tried to fix the axis, but the way matplotlib works is different than matlab I'm used too. The time spans are caluclated from the first shift and start are therefore 8:11-8:16 --> 8:16 - 8:21 etc.

Comment: Secont point (2): This is connected with point 1. If I run the script over multiple days to calculate a average machines needed, various time brackets are in the output and therefore the graph is not readable anymore. Fixed timebrackets would fix this

Comment: MaxU, I hope you understand what small flaws i am talking about. Let me emphasize that you are helping me an awful lot, really, I am very grateful for that! Thanks many many times

Comment: the output look super, but i get this: a = a.set_index('begin').resample(rule='5min').first().reset_index()
TypeError: first() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given). Is it furthermore not possible to predefine the set of intervals, so that we can see from the start of the day till the end of the day how much machines are needed? I will update my question with an graph i would like to make with this, see the question. Many many thanks again!!

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear where I am at now hopefully.

Comment: @Uis234, please don't consider SO as a free coding service - you've changed your question 7 times. Your original question(s) has been answered  and you didn't even upvoted (i don't mean accept) an answer that you are using in "your" code as a small "thank you". Good luck in future!